# Why does this script create one null when it should create four?

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

I'm trying to create a script in After Effects which creates some nulls and a shape layer, and applies some expressions to paths in the shape layer. This is based on the Create Paths from Nulls example script, so I've got a button that works, but it only creates the shape layer and one null. This is the code for creating the nulls:

```
        nl = [];

        for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            nl[i] = createNull(comp);
            nl[i].name = ("Control-0" + i);
            nl[i].label = 11; // should be orange
            var np = nl[i].position;
            np.setValue([100 + (i%2)*100, 100 + (Math.floor(i/2)*100)]);
            var e1 = addSlider(nl[i], "CurveDepth", 1);
            var e2 = addSlider(nl[i], "Roundedness",  0.5);
            var e3 = addSlider(nl[i], "Influence", 1);
            var e4 = addCheckbox(nl[i], "Disable", false);
        }
```

I've also tried replacing `nl[]` with a standard variable in case it's the array causing the problem for some reason, but it doesn't make a difference.

On running the above code (which is a section of the code that runs when the button is pressed) I'd expect to get 4 nulls, but I only get one.

Edit: those i's were all i+1s which they didn't need to be

Comment: Why do you add 1 `nl[i+1]`? The array will start with 2 undefined elements, then have nulls in elements 2-5.

Comment: good question, have edited those out (not that it makes any difference to how the code runs).

Comment: Array indexes start at 0. Why are you starting at 1? I don't know anything about After Effects, but maybe that could be part of the problem.

Comment: I wanted nulls numbered 1 to 4 rather than 0 to 3 - changing the code to `for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) { [...]` makes no difference to the outcome anyway

Comment: Fwiw: Removing the loop, and creating four separate blocks to create the nulls manually, doesn't work either. So it's not the loop.

Comment: I see the `comp` variable never changes, which raises a question for me: is `createNull(comp)` actually creating a new null, or is it returning always the same single object (referred to `comp`, whatever that is)? Please, try checking the value of `nl[1].name`; is it "Control-04" by any chance?